# Tkinter Text widget. Linebreak breaking words

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make the linebreak in a Tkinter Text widget, not breaking words?

Now:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el
it. Donec ornare neque a feugiat tristique. Suspendiss
e ultricies sem eu risus pellentesque interdum. Sed vu
lputate porttitor nibh..."
```

Want:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Donec ornare neque a feugiat tristique. 
Suspendisse ultricies sem eu risus pellentesque 
interdum. Sed vulputate porttitor nibh..."
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html, the option `wrap=tk.WORD` should have this effect.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm

WRAP: This option controls the display of lines that are too wide. Set wrap=WORD and it will break the line after the last word that will fit. With the default behavior, wrap=CHAR, any line that gets too long will be broken at any character